# Do you have a book? Have you a book?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

> **Do** you have a book?
>   **Have** you a book?

What's the difference between them?
What kinds of verbs "do" and "have" are there?

Comment: The two statements are semantically the same. In American English, the first example is far more common.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, it was possible to form a question by simply moving the verb ahead of the subject, like in your second example. If you read Shakespeare, you'll find many such turns of phrase.

**But what *see I*? No Thisbe do I see!**
(from *Midsummer Night's Dream*, Act 5)

Some of that is still preserved in environments that are based on long-standing traditions. It is customary in a U.S. court, to ask:

**"Mr. Smith, what say you?"** instead of "What do you say?"

That said, the auxiliary verbs have taken over completely in common everyday speech. It is always "Do you[...]" rather than the other thing, except in some isolated areas over in England, where instead of asking

**"Do you have a toothbrush?"**

they just might ask you

**"Have you a toothbrush?"**

Comment: British English speakers might also say "Have you got a toothbrush?"

Comment: @200_success: Yes. And?